# vim and snipmate, how to undo expansion

Tags: vim, snipmate

I am using vim with snipmate plugin. How can I undo the expansion?

```
# 1) before expansion
def[tab here]

# 2) expanded
def method_name
end

# How to get to 1) step?
```

Comment: Good question. To clarify, a simple `u` will undo everything including `def` before `<tab>` was pressed.

Comment: Exactly. I would like to have the `def` remained and I would like to undo it directly in `insert` mode. But I am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented such by explicitly creating an *undo point* when triggering the snippet. The challenge is that the same key (`<Tab>` by default) is used for snippet expansion and to jump to the next tab stop.

These parts in `~/.vim/after/plugin/snipMate.vim` should do it. Note that this doesn't deal with the literal tab fallback, as I have remapped the trigger key to something else (see [my fork](https://github.com/inkarkat/snipMate.vim)), and don't care about that part, but you could extract the relevant parts from `TriggerSnippet()` and add those to the conditional.

```
function! s:UndoPointBeforeSnippet()
        return (exists('g:snipPos') ? '' : "\<C-g>u")
endfunction
inoremap <expr> <SID>(UndoPointBeforeSnippet) <SID>UndoPointBeforeSnippet()

ino <silent> <script> <tab> <SID>(UndoPointBeforeSnippet) <c-r>=TriggerSnippet()<cr>
```

Comment: If I understood it correctly, there is no "native" way to achieve it - this plugin just doesn't count with this kind of use, does it? So all I can do is remap triggers and change the plugin's code?

Comment: Yes, there's no built-in feature, and the original snipMate isn't developed any more.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'm accepting this answer and going to fight with that a bit.